# Boost.Intrusive - Constant time Iterator

Tags: c++, boost, stl, containers

Boost.Intrusive can get an Iterator out of an Object-Ref or Object-Pointer in constant time (see here: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_72_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage_when.html). How does that work? Why is this not possible for standard containers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intrusive containers by definition have the information contained *inside* of elements to know how they're located in the container.  A simple example is an intrusive linked list:

```
struct Object {
    Object* next;
    int some_data;
};
```

Obviously, if I have a reference or pointer to `Object`, I can easily find the `next` field, and from there, move to the next element, this is just accessing a member, which is O(1), thus constant time iterators.

With non-intrusive containers, it would look like this:

```
struct Object {
    int some_data;
};
```

Suppose I have a `std::vector` of these, and a pointer or reference to `Object`, I can't work backwards from that to where it is in the `std::vector` without scanning the container to find it (a O(n) operation).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Ok I understood how that works for intrusive Containers, but I am still not sure about the standard containers. Take a std::list, I read that it is implemented using a doubly-linked list, so it should allocate memory for nodes containing a 'next' and 'previous' pointer, but also the object itself, or at least a pointer to the object. If the Object itself is part of that node it should also be possible to get an iterator or not? Or do they only safe pointers?

Comment: If you _know_ that your object lives inside of a `std::list` node, then yes you could theoretically use that knowledge to get to the pointers.  But, given an arbitrary object reference, how do you even know its in the container?  It's not a safe operation so they don't allow it.